# VBA 2010 Add Query Table: Application-defined or Object-Defined Error

Tags: excel, vba

If it were functioning properly, the following code would grab the name of a table from a textbox, concatenate it with 'describe ' and then put the results in a query table.  As it stands, the code fails with 'Run Time Error 1004: Application-Defined or Object-Defined error'

```
Private Sub cmdNew_Click()

Dim TableName As String
Dim NewSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ConnString As String
Dim SQLStatement As String

ConnString = ConnString = "DSN=REMOVED;UID=REMOVED;;DBQ= REMOVED;DBA=W;APA=T;EXC=F;FEN=T;QTO=T;FRC=10;FDL=10;LOB=T;RST=T;BTD=F;BNF=F;BAM=IfAllSuccessful;NUM=NLS;DPM=F;MTS=T;MDI=F;CSR=F;FWC=F;FBS=64000;TLO=O;MLD=0;ODA=F;"
TableName = ActiveSheet.txtTableName.Text
SQLStatement = "desc " & TableName

Set NewSheet = Sheets.Add
NewSheet.Name = TableName

Set qry = NewSheet.QueryTables.Add(ConnString, NewSheet.Range("A1"), SQLStatement)
qry.Refresh
```

End Sub

Comment: I think we need the connection string, just change the passwords, database name ans server names etc. Without it we've no idea what kind of SQL database you are connecting to to get the data.

Comment: "desc [tablename]" isn't valid SQL. Maybe something like `select t.column_name, t.data_type from all_tab_columns t where t.TABLE_NAME='TABLE_NAME_HERE'` might be more useful?  As noted below, mentioning which database you're using would be useful.

Comment: I'm using oracle, conn string added. thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are querying an Oracle DB, the DESC keyword is for sorting a column in descending order, try using the keyword [DESCRIBE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B25329_01/doc/appdev.102/b25108/xedev_sqlplus.htm#BJEEGAII) in full.

If that doesn't work then run your query against the DB server outside of Excel, and see if it gives you a more helpful message?

Comment: I can run the query outside of oracle without any problems.